# JavaScript variable returns undefined throughout if statements and loops

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do the basic twoSum question from leetcode. My `nums` array comes back as undefined throughout this function, and I'm totally lost as to why. I'm sure it's obvious, but I'm having a hard time even troubleshooting it, because no matter where I put console logs in this function, it always says that nums is undefined.

```js
const nums = [2, 7, 11, 15];
const target = 9;

function twoSum() {
    if (nums.length > 0) {
        while (nums === Number) {
            for (let i = 0; i < nums; i++) {
                for (let k = 0; k < nums; k++) {
                    if (i + k == target) {
                        console.log([i, k]);
                    } else {
                        console.log("no result");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        console.log("Array is Empty");
    }
};

console.log(twoSum());
```

Comment: Kindly confirm if the expectation is that `twoSum()` will return any value? If so - please highlight which statement within the method (`twoSum`) returns any value?

Comment: If the values need to be sent to console within `twoSum`, please try this: `twoSumV0 = () => nums.map(x => nums.map(y => x + y === target && console.log([x, y])));
twoSumV0();`. Instead, if the value need to be returned, this should help: `twoSumV1 = () => nums.map(x => nums.map(y => x + y === target ? {x, y} : false)).flat().filter(Boolean).map(({x, y}) => [x, y]);
console.log(twoSumV1());`.

Comment: will `nums === Number` ever be true? i.e. is `Array === Number`?

Comment: @Bravo I was thinking of it wrong. I guess it would be something more like, ```for (i of nums) if (i === Number)``` ?

@jsN00b it doesn't need to return anything, I took the problem from leetcode and was trying to work with it on my own.

Comment: is `1 === Number` ever true

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the following changes in your code. It should fix your issue

- No need for `while (nums === Number)` condition
- replace `i + k == target` with `nums[i] + nums[k] == target`. As i and k are indexes not actual values in array
- Don't use  `console.log("no result");` in else condition. Instead create a flag and check if it's false then do the console.log Otherwise it will console.log everytime `nums[i] + nums[k] !== target`.

```js
const nums = [2, 7, 11, 15];
const target = 9;

let  flag = false;
function twoSum() {
  if (nums.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length -1; i++) {
      for (let k = 1; k < nums.length; k++) {
        if (nums[i] + nums[k] == target) {
        flag = true;
          console.log('indexes', [i, k], 'values', [nums[i], nums[k]]);
        }
      }
    }
    if (!flag) {
    console.log("No Result")
    }

  } else {
    console.log("Array is Empty");
  }
}

twoSum();
```

Comment: Since `i` and `k` loops start from `0` and `1`, respectively, it is evident you do not seek to add an element to itself. So, if the `target` was `4`, in the above example, your code is not meant to return `[2, 2]`. And this is understandable. However, if the `target` was `30`, the code will return `[15, 15]`. This is because both `i` & `k` loops execute till the same end-point. May be make the outer-loop `i` conditional as: `i < nums.length - 1`.

Comment: @jsN00b thanks for pointing it out. I've updated my answer with  ```i < nums.length - 1```

Answer (score 0):

**Assumed objective**

Given an array of integers and a `target`, find any pairs of integers in the array whose sum matches the `target`.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const nums = [2, 7, 11, 15];
const target = 9;

const twoSum = (tgt = target, arr = nums) => (
  arr.forEach(x => 
    arr.forEach(y =>
      x + y === tgt && console.log(x, y)
    )
  )
);

console.log('target = 9');
twoSum();

console.log('target = 4');
twoSum(4);

console.log('target = 30');
twoSum(30);

console.log('target = 55');
twoSum(100) || console.log('no matches');
```

**Explanation**

- Iterate through the array with each item taken as `x`
- Now, iterate again with each item taken as `y`
- If the sum of `x` and `y` matches `target`, then `console.log`

**NOTES**

- As seen in the test cases, same numbers may be considered twice. So, for `target` of `4` the code prints out `2 2`.
- This may be avoided by changing the limits of the outer and inner loops.